# Use PHP ord() function for an entire text

Tags: php, string

I know that the PHP `ord()` function converts a certain character to ASCII. But I want to build a web application that encrypts an inputted text using several methods, and I want to implement a "Text to ASCII" method.

I tried to use the `ord()` function for each character from the inputted string `$text`. That's my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($text); $i++)
   $text[$i] = ord($text[$i]);
```

The problem is, the characters aren't converted properly.

I also tried using `$i<=strlen($text);`, but it just spams my page with some type of error, and I'm pretty sure `$i` doesn't need to reach `strlen($text)` exactly.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is overwriting the string it is trying to convert.  Also `ord()` can produce multiple characters per input character, so this will produce more confusion.

Instead you could build an array for each character, several ways to do it, but sticking with the current method(ish)...

```
$text = "Hello";
$chrs = [];
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($text); $i++)    {
    $chrs[] = ord($text[$i]);
}

print_r($chrs);
```

gives an output of...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 72
    [1] => 101
    [2] => 108
    [3] => 108
    [4] => 111
)
```